# Flight search site with ability to reuse custom filters on avia carriers

Tags: air-travel, flight-search-engines

I often search for flight on which I can travel with my cat in cabin.
There is not much carriers who allow this here, and I only can filter by know list of who does that.

But my flight search engine always resets all filters on change of dates/destinations, so this is not convinient.

Answer (score 4):

The most comprehensive (free) search engine I know is https://matrix.itasoftware.com/search

You can specify which airlines to search (or to exclude) in the routing codes. For example if you want to only search United, Delta and American, you would add a routing code like `UA,DL,AA+`. These don't reset on date changes and you can copied and pasted as text for a new search.

There are routing codes for all types of things (layover cities, aircraft types, alliances, layover duration, number of stops, etc.). It's a powerful engine but has a bit of a learning curve to use it to its full potential.